# How do I get mod_rewrite to work in my home directory?

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I have my PHP files stored under FreeBSD under this directory:

```
/home/david/public_html/code/php
```

In my browser, I access them through this URL:

```
http://192.168.6.7/~david/code/php
```

And I have an htaccess file to rewrite URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test test.php
```

But when I go to http://192.168.6.7/~david/code/php/test in my browser, I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home/david/public_html/code/php/test.php
```

As you can see, the rewrite rule is successful in attempting to redirect test to test.php. But for some reason it fails.

I found this in my apache error log file:

```
File does not exist: /usr/local/www/data/home
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
By the way, if I put this in a web directory and not my home directory, everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the base URL path to `/~david/code/php/` with [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase):

```
RewriteBase /~david/code/php/
```

You should also make clear to set [`UseDir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir) to `public_html`. See also [*Per-user web directories* in the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html).

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But, I now have to keep track of 2 htaccess files. One for my directory, and one for the production directory. Ideally, apache should have a way to set the RewriteBase to the directory that the .htaccess file is in.

Comment: @David Barnes: You could put that directive into your virtual host’s configuration section.